# Validate a simple HTML form via JSON answere

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I´am a UX designer and one of these JS dummie/"HTML coder" guys.

I need help or a hint to validate a simple HTML form via a second request which returns a JSON answere, before the form is send.

I have a really simple HTML form on a landingpage where the user can enter a coupon code:

```
  <form id="tokensubmit" method="GET" action="https://www.xyz/cart.html">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="tokenCodeAdd" id="tokenCodeAdd" size="25" value="" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Please enter Coupon Code">
        </div>
        <input id="input_id" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

If a user enters his Coupon code and hit the submit button, the code will be added to the action URL (https://www.xyz/cart.html) and the User is redirected to this cart.html page. If the coupon code is correct everything is fine. If not he receives an error message on the cart.html page.

So far so good.

BUT: I want to validate the coupon code without redirecting the user to a new website(cart.html). 
The system offers a second URL for this already. A url like:

```
/checkout/validate.html?tokenCode=12345678
```

This returns a JSON answere with a status like:

```
{"error":"Wrong Coupon Code."}
```

if the Coupon code isnt right.
If it is valid, something like:

```
{"error":"null"}
```

returns.

What I am searching for is a simple solution to call the validation URL (validation.html) first on click on the "submit" button, parse the returning JSON, prevent the form from sending if "error" is something else than "null" and print the JSON message ("Wrong Coupon Code.") right above the form input.

If "error" = "null" the forms behavior should not change. It should just open the https://www.xyz/cart.html URL with the tokenCode attached as parameter.

What I´am trying/starting with looks like:

```
$('#tokensubmit').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  var tokenCheck = $(this).find('input[id="tokenCodeAdd"]').val(); 
  $.ajax({
    url: '/checkout/validate.html'+tokenCheck,
    type: 'GET', 
    success: function(data){
      var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Its just the beginning, I know. The real parsing part is missing and the error message output if the validation fails, or the redirect if not.

Anyone who could help? 
And thx in advanced!

Small hint: The form is placed on a WordPress driven landingpage, so PHP and JQuery is an option.

Comment: Appreciate you've fleshed out your scenario, but you've not really made clear what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have for getting the validation is *almost* correct:

```
$('#tokensubmit').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  var tokenCheck = $(this).find('input[id="tokenCodeAdd"]').val(); 
  $.ajax({
    // either attach the parameter like you are trying to do directly to the url,
    // but in this way:
    url: '/checkout/validate.html?tokenCode='+tokenCheck,
    // or give the URL parameter(s) as data object to jQuery:
    data: {
        tokenCode: tokenCheck
    }
    type: 'GET',
    // if you specify the dataType you want to receive as json,
    // jQuery will parse it for you already
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        // now you can check the data for error or not, for example like:
        if(data.error == null){
            // do something (most likely REALLY submit the form now?)               
        }else{
            alert('tokenCode invalid');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can send through a data parameter and it will work out how to place it in the URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/checkout/validate.html',
    type: 'GET', 
    data: {"tokenCode": tokenCheck}
    success: function(data){
      var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
    }
});
```

I would also advise not doing an Ajax request at all if tokenCheck is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn 't it be easier to check the coupon code when the user leaves the input field? First the example while submitting the whole form.

```
$('#tokensubmit').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var validationSuccess = false;

    $.ajax({
        url : '/checkout/validate.html',
        type : 'GET',
        data : { tokenCode : $('#tokeninput').val() }
        success : function(response) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(response);
            if (data.error === null) {
                validationSuccess = true;
            }
        }

        if (validationSuccess === true) {
            $('#tokensubmit').off('submit').submit();
        }
    });
```

So what we 've done here? The submit event listener is nearly the same you 've done. We prevent the default submitting of the form and do an ajax request for validation the input value. If the request returns no error as response, we simply unbind the submit event listener from the form and submit the form again.

In my opinion it would be better to work with the blur event listener on the input field. In combination you could use the HTML5 Constraint Validation API. So you don 't have to submit the form and the ajax request would be done on blurring the input field. I think that would be the better user experience.

So here 's the blur event listener:

```
<input type="text" name="the-input-field" id="the-input-field" value="" required>

$('#the-input-field').on('blur', function(event) {
    var element = this;
    $.ajax({
        url : '/checkout/validate.html',
        type : 'GET',
        data : { tokenCode : element.val() }
        success : function(response) {
            var data = $.parseJSON(response);
            if (data.error !== null) {
                element.setCustomValidity('Your input is invalid!');
                // place some error message elsewhere in the markup
            } else {
                element.setCustomValidity('');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

First we placed the required Attribute in the input element. It marks the input element as required. So if it 's empty you could not submit the form. Then we placed the blur event listener, which is doing the ajax request. If the response is false, we place a custom error via setCustomValidity. It is a native HTML5 Constraint Validation API function. If the custom error on the input element is set, you could not submit the form. If the user enters another token the request is done again on leaving the input element. If the token is valid, the custom error message will be removed and the form can be submitted.